# VS Code Open new terminal from powershell

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

VS Code (Windows 10)

What I want to achieve from ps1 script :

- open 4 terminal tabs
- first one run python venv and then run django server
- second one run python venv and then run django shell
- third one run react (yarn start)
- fourth normal powershell for git and other

I created a powershell script that I run from default opened terminal. Now I'd like to open a new terminal tab from first one.

Can I fire a vs code command shortcut (Ctrl+`) or a vs code command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) from terminal ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: @gvee That isn't an answer. That link provides NO information relevant to the asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem.

I created a [VS Code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) and I used the [extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api).

```js
// Create a terminal Window
const term = vscode.window.createTerminal("terminal_name");

// Write any powershell command
term.sendText("cd C:\\path\\to\\follow\\");

// Any other command
term.sendText("yarn start");

// Create a second terminal
const secTerm = vscode.window.createTerminal("second_terminal_name");

secTerm.sendText("cd C:\\another\\path\\to\\follow\\");

secTerm.sendText("py manage.py runserver");

// and so one
```

Comment: still a bit complex for a seemingly simple task