# How to get host operating system name from visual studio code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my extension I have to call functions depending on the host operating system, how do I get infos about host operating system ?

Comment: From briefly looking over the [VSCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) it seems to be intended to be used as a cross-platform API, so ideally there should not be a need to make this kind of distinction. Are you missing any specific capability?

Comment: It's related to my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983314/vs-code-open-new-terminal-from-powershell/56439295#56439295 I use VS Extension to open terminal and send some shell commands. Some are slightly different between operating systems.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows

```
process.platform==='win32'
```

is true, and that is still the case on my 64-bit windows 11.

On MacOs

```
process.platform==='darwin'
```

On Linux Mint

```
process.platform==='linux'
```

On my wsl/ubuntu installation

```
process.platform==='linux'
```

(.. it would also be nice to distinguish wsl from a full linux os)

There is no need to import/require `process`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `os` package from node.  See [os.type](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#ostype):

`const os = require('os');` or `import` it

> Returns the operating system name as returned by uname(3). For
> example, it returns `Linux` on Linux, `Darwin` on macOS, and
> `Windows_NT` on Windows.

I do not believe you need to install the `os` package separately - it is made available to extension authors automatically.

Comment: Thank you, this is what works for me:
const os - require('os');
os.platform() == 'win32'

Answer (score 0):

This is [what I did for my extension](https://github.com/mausworks/tidier/blob/7fb6e78747e43b00605d877fddf2d0e6c75648d4/packages/tidier-vscode/src/context.ts#L154-L167), it isn't the most robust solution but it works well enough for my purposes:

```js
import { env } from 'vscode';

const isWindows = () => Boolean(env.appRoot && env.appRoot[0] !== "/");
```

The rationale is that all UNIX-like OS:es will have a root starting with `/`, and a Windows-based install will have something like `C:`.

If you don't mind having a hard-dependency on Node internals, [you can use `process.platform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684009/4697655) instead.