# Running `keyboard shortcut commands` in a bash script to open new terminal in VS Code

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, sh, keyboard-shortcuts

When starting up my local environment it is necessary for me to start 5 repositories and run a few other commands.

I generally open up VS Code and start each repository in its own terminal, the commands include:

- `docker start...`
- `docker-compose.yml up`
- `make...`
- `npm run serve`
- `python3...`
- `stripe listen`

It's possible to to open a new terminal instance in VS Code with the `ctrl` + `shift` + `` ` `` keyboard shortcut as well as to split the terminal with `ctrl` + `shift` + `5`.

I'm wanting to, however, write a simple `sh` script to automate these tedious and repetitive tasks by executing the aforementioned `keyboard shortcuts` from within my script. I, unfortunately, can't seem to find any literature on the matter, and it would make sense to me that this functionality would exist, could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

The closest "solution" I've come across is [VS Code Open new terminal from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983314/vs-code-open-new-terminal-from-powershell) but this makes use of creating a [VS Code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) and using the [extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api); which isn't exactly what I'm wanting to do but could be a workaround.

This question is focused on being able to open a new terminal from within a `sh` script but is open-ended in the sense that I'm also asking if it is possible to execute any `keyboard "commands" / shortcuts` from within a script?

Any, and all, help will be highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: the shell has no knowledge of who is on the other end of `stdin` and `stdout`. You can send commands from a keybinding to a terminal, maybe you can also start a new terminal, use `multi-command` to combine all commands to 1 key binding

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8, but I still don't know how one would go about adding the keyboard shortcut commands in a bash script? I can't type out `ctrl` + `shift` + \`, so how does one go about it? Additionally, are you referring to [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) when you mention `multi-command`?

Comment: yes, use VSC to type commands in the terminal, there is a `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` command to send keys to the terminal, move the bas script to VSC and send the commands to the terminal

Comment: Okay perfect, I fully understand, thank you for your appreciated assistance @rioV8!

Comment: https://github.com/biel-correa/waiter